# How to assign array values at run time

Tags: c#

Consider I have an Array,

```
int[] i = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Here I have assigned values for it. But in my problem I get these values only at runtime.
How can I assign them to an array.

For example:

I get the max size of array from user and the values to them now how do I assign them to the array int [].

Or can I use anyother data types like ArrayList etc which I can cast to Int[] at the end?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the easiest is to use `List<T>`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);
int[] arr = list.ToArray();
```

Otherwise, you need to allocate an array of suitable size, and set via the indexer.

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 5;
```

This second approach is not useful if you can't predict the size of the array, as it is expensive to reallocate the array every time you add an item; a `List<T>` uses a doubling strategy to minimize the reallocations required.

Comment: obj.myIntArray = (new List<int> { 1,2 }).ToArray();

Comment: Is there no way to use "{1,2,3,4,5}"?

Comment: @Xonatron yes, collection initializers have been added over the last 7 years, see lamarant's comment. However, if the values are known at compile time, you can just go straight to an array *anyway*

Answer (score 18):

You mean?

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
array = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
array = new int[] { 100, 53, 25, 787, 39 };
array = new int[] { 100, 53, 25, 787, 39, 500 };
```

Comment: How is this not the top answer?

Answer (score 8):

Use `List<int>` and then call `ToArray()` on it at the end to create an array. But do you *really* need an array? It's generally easier to work with the other collection types. As Eric Lippert wrote, "[arrays considered somewhat harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx)".

You *can* do it explicitly though, like this:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int size = ReadInt32FromConsole("Please enter array size");

        int[] array = new int[size];
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            array[i] = ReadInt32FromConsole("Please enter element " + i);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished:");
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }

    static int ReadInt32FromConsole(string message)
    {
        Console.Write(message);
        Console.Write(": ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        // Include error checking in real code!
        return int.Parse(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. I almost never use arrays anymore now that generic lists are just so damned easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array, whose size varies during the execution, then you should use another data structure. A generic List will do. Then, you can dynamically add elements to it.

**Edit:** Marc posted his answer while I was writing mine. This was exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the below line instead of calling a separate function:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter array size");
        int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] array = new int[size];
        for (int i=0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter element " + i);
            array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished:");
        foreach (int i in array)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
```